# c++ cannot convert from 'int **' to 'const int **'

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
int** a;
const int** b;
b = a;
```

This code gives an error:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int **' to 'const int **'
Conversion loses qualifiers
```

Why i am not able to perform the cast?

When operating simple pointers it works ok.

```
int* a;
const int* b;
b = a;
```

Comment: I think neither should be possible..

Comment: What's made `const` in your 1st case is the inner `int`, this constness can't be casted away in the assignment.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you were able to perform this cast. Consider:

```
const int n = 42;
const int* cp = &n;

int* p;
int** a = &p;

const int** b;
b = a;  // hypothetical, doesn't compile
*b = cp;  // equivalent to p = cp;
*p = 84;  // equivalent to n = 84: oops
```

Therefore, allowing an implicit cast from `int**` to `const int**` would allow a program to violate const correctness.